# Is there a category-theoretic version of Girard's paradox?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

Suppose, to approximate [Girard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_U#Girard%27s_paradox), that we have a category whose collection of objects includes itself. Can we conclude that such a category has no initial object, or something similar?

I don't have a real motivation for this; it just occurred to me while reading a paper. Following [Coquand 1992, "The paradox of trees in type theory"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01995104), let a normal object be an object with only one endomorphism (its identity morphism). Then I think Coquand's argument can be restated to say that a category whose objects are normal, and who is among its own objects, has no initial object.

Comment: It is difficult to make sense of the question. The usual frameworks in which mathematicians study category theory either do not permit such self-membership (because it is based on e.g. ZFC set theory), or do not even consider such propositions to be well-formed (because e.g. there is no global membership relation).

Comment: As @ZhenLin writes, your question is at best subtle and under-specified. Depending on where you take it from here, it might become controversial as well. Feferman has papers, incl. *Foundations of Unlimited Category Theory: What remains to be done*, about desiderata for a consistent "naive" category theory. Ernst has an article which claims to show that the desiderata are inconsistent. I've heard the latter paper described in very unfavorable terms, saying that if Ernst's objection made sense, a [much simpler argument](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03272)(p3) involving *Set* would have worked.

Comment: I don't know whether these criticisms are right or wrong, but it makes me suspect that, unless you phrase your query much more specifically (say by restricting your attention to a fixed axiomatic system) the question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts.

Comment: I agree with all of the comments and am voting to close.